# zsh: How to identify which file zsh completion function comes from?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In zsh, how can one know which file a completion function is defined in or comes from?

`which` can print the source code of a completion but it does not give any information about where I can find the file that contains the completion script. For instance, `which _git` in a zsh shell gives the following output:

```bash
❯❯❯ which _git
_git () {
    local _ret=1 
    local cur cword prev
    #...  (omitted) ...
    let _ret && _default && _ret=0 
    return _ret
}
```

whereas `which git` (commands or executables) gives the exact path(s):

```
❯❯❯ which -a git 
/opt/homebrew/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
```

I know the completion functions must be somewhere in `$fpath`, so one could search `$fpath` to find a `_completion` file.

```bash
❯❯❯ for f in $fpath; do \ls $f/_git 2>/dev/null; done 
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zsh/5.9/share/zsh/functions/_git
```

But is there any easy way or built-in command for doing this?

Comment: `type _git` gives me: `_git is a shell function from /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git`

Answer (score 1):

The following function is similar to the `where` builtin, but looks for files in `$fpath`. It finds functions that are loadable from a file of the same name. If there are multiple matching files, it only reports the first one.

```
function whence-function {
    emulate -L zsh
    local name locations ret=0
    for name; do
        locations=($^fpath/$name(N))
        if (($#locations != 0)); then
            print -l -- $locations[1]
        else
            ret=1
        fi
    done
    return $ret
}
```

If a function is already loaded, I don't think zsh keeps track of which file it was loaded from. So for example, once `_git` is loaded, a lot of auxiliary functions `_git_xxx` are also loaded, but something like `whence-function _git_commands` won't tell you where to find `_git_commands`, you have to guess that it comes from the same file as `_git`.